# get Image object from path name

Tags: c#, .net, image

Given a path and filename how can I get the `Image` object:

```
Image image = ...(filename)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want to call the [static `FromFile` method on the `Image` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6ytk052.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to use a Bitmap object (which inherits from Image) like so:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imagePath);
```

(This works for all image formats, not just *.bmp as the name might imply.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're playing with images in memory, I've found that bobpowell.net has a GREAT site for GDI work in C#.

No.. I'm not related to, associated with or hired by Bob Powell. I just really enjoy his work. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get original filename with extention
            string filenameWithPath = "C:\pictures\peanutbutterjellytime.jpg;
            filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filenameWithPath);
```

Comment: The OP is trying to create an Image, not a filename.

Comment: This helped me get the filename, since at first I was trying a Split but knew there was an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're having trouble getting the path of the resource (trickiest part) you can do a :

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string[] names = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
foreach (string name in names)
{
   Console.WriteLine( name );
}
```

Which shows all paths for resources.