# How to convert ImageURL to File

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I getting product imageurl from database like that "~/ProductImages/OdrinDigital.com/26/UML 1.jpg" and i want to convert this url to HttpFileCollectionBase format after that i want to push array this converted file.[image]

As you can see in the Array, the first two elements appear as url and the third element appear as file format. I want to do is convert these ImageURLs to File format

Comment: maybe this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432245/get-image-object-from-path-name

Comment: @Ali7091 i need to converting process in javascript side. Just i must convert this url to file and push array thats it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var file;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'your image url', true);
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        file = new File([this.response],'fileName');
    }
};
xhr.send();
```